# Installing Ubuntu server without a monitor

Tags: server, headless

I recently acquired a laptop that works perfectly except that it has a broken monitor. Only the top quarter of the monitor works, so I can still use the cli. It does have a VGA and HDMI connector on it that work as well. I Installed Ubuntu server on it by swapping the hard drive with another computer and installing it there. Now I have Ubuntu running on the laptop, but I cannot get it to connect to the internet via Ethernet cable or WiFi (WiFi would only be temporary). I am pretty sure this is because the Ubuntu installer is using the hardware configuration of the computer I installed it on. Any suggestions on what I could do to fix this? Maybe have the installer automatically reconfigure the installation?

Comment: Hardware configuration of the installer machine is irrelevant. Linux kernel will load  hardware drivers for whatever is the system using. That is, if there are drivers. Many are supported but not all. Likely case is that you have network cards that are Broadcom or other proprietary manufacturer. I suggest you use a wifi usb dongle with RTL 8191 chipset. These are supported out of the box. There are also usb to Ethernet converters.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing to connect to WiFi?

Comment: @Eduardo Cola I tried using iwconfig, but it doesn't come preinstalled on the server edition, so I can't really use it until I get an Ethernet connection working, or just put the hard disk back in the machine I installed the OS on in the first place to install iwconfig.

Comment: What about ifconfig? And you can use ifup with /etc/network/interfaces if you know the interface name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed, just needed to use ifconfig up